# Chat link doesn't go to Agora

Tags: bug, chat, stackexchange

On most SE sites, when I click on "Chat" link on the top left StackExchange dropdown menu next to the site name, it takes me to the site's main chatroom.

On Politics.SE, it takes me to general SE chat listing all chatrooms; despite the link being site-specific:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=politics.stackexchange.com

The correct link seems to be (based on bluefeet's comment)

http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=politics.stackexchange.com

Comment: What site takes you directly into the room?  That link should be taking you to the list of chatrooms on a particular site.

Comment: @bluefeet - ah, yes, correct. The problem is that this site's link takes you to ALL chat rooms (43 pages), not just of this site (ordered by last activity, after listing chat rooms on this site). Can you reproduce?

Comment: Hmm I'm not able to reproduce that issue.  When I click the chat link it takes me to the site tab, not the all tab.

Comment: @bluefeet - figured it out! 2 bugs (features, rather?) combined: (1) The tab is persisted. So if you ever go to "all" tab, all subsequent chat visits will go there as well. (2) the "all" tabs STILL shows Politics.SE as a site in URL, which may be technically needed for other tabs to work but confused the otters out of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! 2 bugs (features, rather?) combined:

1. The tab you are on is persisted. So if you ever go to "all" tab, all subsequent chat visits will go there as well.
2. The "all" tabs STILL shows Politics.SE as a site as part of URL, which may be technically needed for other tabs to work but confused the heck out of me, since it looked like I was looking at the site specific tab.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it should really take you to this view:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=site&sort=active